# In C how do I compile and then create an executable file with a header and two c files?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation, header

I have three C files in total. One is a header [`.h`] file, two are source [`.c`] files.

The `.h` file is called `encryption.h` and the corresponding source file is `encryption.c`. The `encryption.c` has logic, but no `main()` function. My second c file is called `main.c`. There I have the `main()` function that calls methods from `encryption.c`.

I am compiling these files within terminal on Mac OSx. I am confused on how to compile this, I have tried the following:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c encryption.c
gcc -c encryption.h
gcc main.o encryption.o encryption.g.gch -o encrypt
```

This doesn't seem to work though, it says I have a precompiled-header already. I tried finding the answer online, I know it has to be simple, but I haven't had much luck. What is the issue here?

Comment: `gcc -c encryption.h`----> you don't compile header files.

Comment: Thank you @SouravGhosh. What would be the appropriate way of going about this?

Comment: Just don't compile the header file, and don't link with the precompiled header file, only the object files generated from the source files.

Comment: I don't know, evidently whatever happens to a compiled .h file with gcc....

Comment: From what I looked up online they're precompiled header files used to optimize performance in some aspect. @JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't compile the header file. Header files are meant to be *included* to the source files (using `#include` directive, in `c`). Just compile the source files and link them together. Something like

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc -c encryption.c
gcc main.o encryption.o -o encrypt
```

or, for shorthand,

```
gcc main.c encryption.c -o encrypt
```

---

<sup>Note: If you're bothered about the *presence* (or absence) of header files while compilation, check the pre-processed output of each source files using `gcc -E` option.</sup>

Comment: What's the point of the header file then? I am really familiar with Java, and I see the header file like an interface. Is there no point in having it if it's not going to be used then? I mean unless there are constants in the header file, then that's a different story, but my professor wants the skeleton code for my functions in that file. . .

Comment: @MiguelJ. Updated the answer. Hope that helps. :-)

Comment: The point of header files is, basically, so that every code file which `#include`s it knows how the functions declared there work. Also knows about `#defines` and types ...